# errors: [{message: "Cannot query field "..." on type "Mutation". Did you mean "..."?",…}]

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I am working with apollo client and when logout mutation called I get this error

```
errors: [{message: "Cannot query field "Logout" on type "Mutation". Did you mean "Login"?",…}]
```

My Mutation is

```
mutation Logout($token: String!){
  Logout(token: $token){
    status
    logout
    msg
  }
}
```

This mutation is working in playground but not in application.
Can`t understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: can you place the mutation definition also.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error because `logout mutation` implementation code was not present, it was in another branch. SO I switched to that branch which has the code and error get resolved.